# Unable to Consume Webflux Streaming Response in React-Native client

Tags: react-native, xmlhttprequest, spring-webflux

I've a reactive streaming api built on spring 5 webflux running on netty server with the following syntax -

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/customer/messages/stream", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux<Messages> fetchAllMessagesForCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerRequest)
```

Now to consume this from my react-native app, I tried using [fetch Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams) but it didn't work because of [react-native issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9629). So I tried with good old xhr

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log("state change.. state: "+ xhr.readyState);

  if(xhr.readyState == 3) {
    var newData = xhr.response.substr(xhr.seenBytes);
    console.log("newData", newData);
    xhr.seenBytes = xhr.responseText.length;
  }
};
```

This works to some extent but with the following **issues**

1. Response consumption is not sync with publishing streams and most of the times multiple streams get combined and thrown to the client.
2. `xhr.responseText` essentially appends all the streams and keeps growing bigger which seems like an *anti-pattern* as the whole idea was to break down huge responses into smaller chunks and consume them individually.

**Is there any good alternative to handle the streaming response in react-native ? Suggestions are welcome.**